# How Protected the folder

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Without Environment.UserName I want to Protected the folder  .

My expecting is No one can't able to open the folder . Its always should be Protection.

```
string folderPath = @"C:\ProgramData\Utthunga\uDDxSuite\Asset";
                string adminUserName = "ABC";// getting your adminUserName
                DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath);
                FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);
                ds.RemoveAccessRule(fsa)`enter code here` Directory.SetAccessControl(folderPath, ds);
```